# A lattice is distributive iff the pentagon and the diamond cannot be embedded in it

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

While reading about lattices properties i found this theory:

> A lattice is distributive iff the pentagon and the diamond cannot
> be embedded in it.

It is stated in many books but I cant find the proof of it anywhere. Can someone point me a book where can i find it?

Comment: Try [this one](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/UALG/univ-algebra2012.pdf). There are many, but this one's for free...

Comment: To complete @amrsa's comment, look at Theorem 3.6, p. 12

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Yes, I could have mentioned that, but I was lazy to check that information :( And also include in the link text, "A course in Universal Algebra" by Burris and Sankappanavar, instead of "this one" which is not very informative for someone who just reads the comment. Thanks for the complementary information.

Comment: There's also a perfectly good explanation in wikipedia on distributivity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Distributivity -- where they show for those two embedded lattices how distributivity breaks down. With citation to a textbook.